# Emulate Mac trackpad with MS Precision trackpad

Tags: macos, driver, hardware, multi-touch, trackpad

I'm currently working on a hackintosh machine with a precision trackpad, which is currently being handled by [VoodooPS2](https://github.com/RehabMan/OS-X-Voodoo-PS2-Controller) which is the staple for hackintosh keyboard/trackpad support. The precision trackpad is Microsoft's attempt to rival the Mac trackpad and as such provides all the same multitouch information that the Mac trackpad does. As a research project and for some utility, I'd like to create a relay that uses calls from a precision trackpad to emulate an actual Mac trackpad for proper gesture support and better tracking.

Some resources:

**[FingerMgmt](http://www.makeitgo.ws/articles/fingermgmt/)**

- Touches on the information held in trackpad multitouch support in macOS.
- Information taken from the trackpad includes the x,y coordinates of finger touches as well as the minor / major axes of touch points. Touch points are actually treated as ellipsoids instead of circles; luckily this information doesn't seem to be used that much by the operating system.
- The bottom of the page mentions that the Mac trackpad most likely supplies a 2d bitmap of pressure data to the OS; precision trackpads don't seem to provide this so trackpad data will have to be supplied at the multitouch level.

**[Precision trackpad](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn467314(v=vs.85).aspx)**

- Information sent about a finger contact includes x,y (of course) along with a "confidence" value for palm rejection and the width and height of a contact.
- The height and width of a finger contact should be able to be used to estimate the major / minor ellipsoid for Mac multitouch.

The theory seems to check out; the challenge will be creating a virtual trackpad device and relaying / translating input from the actual hardware to it.

Is this a possibility? What would be a good way to start to play with the raw data from the precision trackpad on macOS?